# pandas to_timedelta ignoring unit parameter?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, dataframe, timedelta

I have a dataframe with two columns of interest `['Response_hour','Incident_date']` like so:

```
Response_hour  Incident_date
08             2011-01-01  
07             2011-01-01
NaN            2011-01-02
```

When I run

```
df['temp'] = ddf['Incident_date'] + pd.to_timedelta(df.Response_hour, unit='h')
df['temp'][0]
```

I get:

```
Timestamp('2011-01-01 00:00:00.000000008')
```

Why is `to_timedelta` ignoring the unit that I've specified?

Comment: What if you do df[‘temp’] = df[‘temp’].astype(datetime) and then did df[‘temp’][0]... don’t forget to import datetime at the top

Comment: @skarchmit I get the same result unfortunately

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using an *int* conversion. In case you have NaN values you need to replace these first by 0. By adding 0 the Indident_date remains the same.

```
# Use fillna() to replace the values by 0
df['Response_hour'] = df['Response_hour'].fillna(0)
# force type to int
df['Response_hour'] = df['Response_hour'].astype(int)
df['temp'] = df['Incident_date'] + pd.to_timedelta(df.Response_hour, unit='h')
```

Gives:

```
  Incident_date  Response_hour                temp
0    2011-01-01              8 2011-01-01 08:00:00
1    2011-01-01              7 2011-01-01 07:00:00
2    2011-01-01              0 2011-01-01 00:00:00
3    2011-01-01              0 2011-01-01 00:00:00
```

Comment: I get `TypeError: cannot convert the series to <class 'int'>`

Comment: @UserIsStuck, changed it

Comment: One thing I didn't mention is the Response_hour column has null values.  astype(int) throws an error because of the nulls

Comment: as being NaN values ?, pls. extend your post so that there is a https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve, saves time on both sides

Comment: @UserIsStuck I've extended it to handle NaN values